# Mousedown event suppressing focusout event?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an application in which there is a password field. We want to show the password as text to the user when the user holds the mouse over a eye Icon. However on some occasions the focus out event does not get called. This is what the code looks like. Does the mousedown event suppress the focus out event. The conversion to text and password works fine but the value does not get bound to the model.

```
$(document).on('mousedown mouseup', '.passfield', function (event) {
    togglepasswordreset(event);
});

window.togglepasswordreset = function (event) {
    var element = event.currentTarget;
    if (element) {
        if (event.type == 'mousedown') {
            $(element).parent().children('input').attr('type', 'text');
        }
        else {
            $(element).parent().children('input').attr('type', 'password');
        }
    }
};
```

This is what the html looks like

```
<div class="field">
    <span class="controls passfield" for="showpass"><b class="icon_eye"></b></span>
     @*<input type="checkbox" value="Show password" class="passcheckbox" id="showpass" tabindex="-1" data-bind="click:onShowPass">*@
     <label for="inputEmail" class="floatLblDn">@Resources.Password</label>
     <input type="password" class="floatTxt myStyle" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" data-bind="value: Password">
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to create the `togglepasswordreset` in each event move that outside the event handler.

Comment: Can you post the html you have that creates the `.passfield` eye icon?

Comment: Updated with html. While copying and pasting the function became embedded within the handler. Actual code is not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a helping example for you.

**HTML**

```
<div>
        <input type="password" class="passfield" id="passf" />
        <label style="margin-left: -30px; background: #ffde00; cursor: pointer;"        for="#passf">See</label>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('label').click(function(event) {
        });
        $('label').mousedown(function(event) {
            $('.passfield').attr('type', 'text');
        });
        $('label').mouseup(function(event) {
            $('.passfield').attr('type', 'password');
            $('.passfield').focus();
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the mouseover and mouseout events.

I have created a jsFiddle to show you https://jsfiddle.net/uxy0def1/

Just enter a password and mouseover the text "SHOW PASSWORD"

html

```
<div class="field"> <span class="controls passfield" for="showpass"><b class="icon_eye">SHOW PASSWORD</b></span>
    <input type="password" class="floatTxt myStyle" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" data-bind="value: Password">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.passfield', function (event) {
    $(this).parent().children('input').attr('type', 'text');
});

$(document).on('mouseout', '.passfield', function (event) {
    $(this).parent().children('input').attr('type', 'password');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The [mouseup event](https://api.jquery.com/mouseup/) may not fire on the `.passfield` if the user drags away onto another element;

> If the user clicks outside an element, drags onto it, and releases the
>   button, this is still counted as a mouseup event. This sequence of
>   actions is not treated as a button press in most user interfaces, so
>   it is usually better to use the click event unless we know that the
>   mouseup event is preferable for a particular situation.

Similarly the [mousedown](https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) event may not work as expected;

> If the user clicks on an element, drags away from it, and releases the
>   button, this is still counted as a mousedown event. This sequence of
>   actions is treated as a "canceling" of the button press in most user
>   interfaces, so it is usually better to use the click event unless we
>   know that the mousedown event is preferable for a particular
>   situation.

Here I would bind the mousedown to `.passfield` but have mouseup on the whole document. Alter the function so rather than toggle mouseup always reverts to password and mousedown sets as text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show password when mouse over some element and hide when it's leave, you may use mouseover and mouseout events.

Comment: Sorry. I mistakenly edited your answer. Cancel that.